# Touchable opacity event handling stops working on elevation

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have a fixed header component with a touchableopacity on it which works. It's elevation is set to 10. Below it I have a view which I scroll up under the fixed header. It's elevation is set to 0. As soon as the view scrolls under the fixed header, I lose all touch events on the fixed header.

I'm presuming that the events are propagating down through the header to the scrolling view but am not sure how to stop this?

I have tried to handle this by setting onStartShouldSetResponder on the header but this does not help.

Component:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }} >
    <Header {...this.props} />
        <Collapsible max={160} min={0} renderHeader={<MenuHeader {...params} />} 
           renderContent={<View><FlatList
                            data={menuitems}
           renderItem={({ item }) => (<MenuLineItem>{item.name}</MenuLineItem>)}}
                        /></View>}
       />                    
</View>
```

Header:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', height:88, paddingTop: 10, backgroundColor, elevation: 10}} onStartShouldSetResponder={()=>{return true;}}>               
    <TouchableOpacity underlayColor={'transparent'} onPress={() => { this.goHome(); }}>
       <View>
          <Image source={require('logo.png')} ></Image>
       </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: I seem to have corrected it by setting a zIndex on the header view but the zIndex value is ignored when rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved it now as follows:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }} >
     <Collapsible max={160} min={0} renderHeader={<MenuHeader {...params} />} 
           renderContent={<View><FlatList
                            data={menuitems}
           renderItem={({ item }) => (<MenuLineItem>{item.name}</MenuLineItem>)}}
                        /></View>}
       />
    <Header {...this.props} style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0}} />                    
</View>
```

So I've moved the Header below the scrolling view but then absolute positioned it above.